# Trouble selecting "Fully Preemptible Kernel (Real-Time)" when configuring/compiling from source

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, configuration, real-time

I am trying to compile the 5.4 kernel with the latest stable PREEMPT_RT patch (5.4.28-rt19) but for some reason can't select the **Fully Preemptible Kernel (RT)** option inside *make nconfig/menconfig*.

I've compiled the 4.19 rt patch before, and it was as simple as copying the current config (/boot/config-4.18-xxx) to the new `.config`, and the option would show. Now I only see:

```
No Forced Preemption (Server)
Voluntary Kernel Preemption (Desktop)
Preemptible Kernel (Low-Latency Desktop)
```

And if I press F4 to "*ShowAll*", I do see the option:

```
XXX Fully Preemptible Kernel (Real-Time)
```

But cannot select it. I've tried manually setting it in `.config` with various PREEMPT options like:

```
CONFIG_PREEMPT=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_BASE=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_FULL=y
```

But it never shows. I just went ahead and compiled it with `CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_FULL=y` (which is overwritten before when saving the `make nconfig`), but it seems it's still not the fully preemptive kernel that is installed.

With 4.19, `uname -a` would show something like:

`Linux 4.19.106-rt45 #2 SMP PREEMPT RT <date>`

or something like that, but now it will just say:

`Linux 5.4.28-rt19 #2 <date>`

Anyone know what I'm missing here?

OS: CentOS 8.1.1911

Kernel: 4.18.0-147.8.1 -> 5.4.28-rt19

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please enable EXPERT mode after launching `make nconfig`/`menuconfig`. Then you'll be able to select Fully Preemptible Kernel (RT) option.

Comment: For folks wondering how to enable expert mode as suggested in the answer, I was compiling a 5.6.19 kernel and I wasn't able to figure how to select that expert mode. So I first selected embedded system option (General Setup -> Embedded System) then I selected General Setup -> Preemption Model -> Fully Preemptible Kernel. I hope this helps!

Comment: I enabled "Embedded System" in `menuconfig` but the fully preempt option still does not appear for me. I'm using 4.19.35 (with .37 rt20 patch) for the iMX8MM (ARM64). I've also tried manually adding `CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_FULL=y` to `.config` but Yocto overrides it and won't compile with the flag.

Comment: Was it just the Preemption Model that you could not find? After enabling "Embedded System" you need to go back and then go to "Processor type and features"; then select the Preemption Model in that page. If Fully Preemptible Kernel still did not show there then not sure

Answer (score 3):

The approach which was taken by utk did not fully work for me.

I work with an ARM64 server (ThunderX CN8890) in my thesis and I could not get the Fully Preemptible Kernel (RT) to appear in the menuconfig no matter what I did.

After checking kernel/Kconfig.preempt
I got the answer:

```
config PREEMPT_RT
    bool "Fully Preemptible Kernel (Real-Time)"
    depends on EXPERT && ARCH_SUPPORTS_RT
    select PREEMPTION
```

-> https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/Kconfig.preempt#L61

I had enabled the EXPERT flag (via the toggle Embedded System as krishna chaitanya in the comment above) but my configuration file was missing the entry: CONFIG_ARCH_SUPPORTS_RT

When I entered the flag manually, it would be overwritten by a make step.
To enable this flag by default open the file arch/Kconfig and search for the entry: ARCH_SUPPORTS_RT. (in nano press CTRL+W for search)

Change the entry from

```
config ARCH_SUPPORTS_RT
    bool
```

to

```
config ARCH_SUPPORTS_RT
    def_bool y
```

When you now also have the EXPERT (General Setup -> Embedded System) flag enabled you should see the option "Fully Preemptible Kernel (Real-Time)" under General Setup -> Preemption Model.

Forcing the flag is a hacky way to solve this problem, still it worked for me.

Comment: You are my hero, my friend

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer would work for kernel versions up to 5.8. Starting from 5.9, KVM needs to be disabled before the Fully Preemptable option appears. The option can be found in:

`Virtualization -> Kernel-based Virtual Machine (KVM) support`

I found this out thanks to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/616822/231640 and https://lore.kernel.org/linux-rt-users/20200824154605.v66t2rsxobt3r5jg@linutronix.de

Answer (score 0):

I think you are either missing the Real-time patch or using the Linux kernel source with the RT patch:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/rt/linux-stable-rt.git/

See also [Linux Foundation wiki Real-time page](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/realtime/start)