# Real-time patch on Linux 5.9.1 does not show fully-preemptible option for arm64 option

Tags: linux, kernel, real-time

I am trying to get my own custom Real-time Linux on a Raspberry Pi 4B. My status is this:

1. I built the Linux 5.9.1 version, and have my own version of U-Boot, RFS with which I am able to successfully load and start the kernel, mount RFS, as well as reach the Kernel console also.
2. I need to apply the Real-time patch on top of the Linux Kernel that I am building and so I used the corresponding patch for Linux 5.9.1. Since I am building a 64-bit kernel, I use the following command to get into the Kernel config and update the preemptible option:

```
    make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-rpi3-linux-gnu- menuconfig
```

But **I do not see the fully preemptible kernel option** here:
.config - Linux/**arm64 5.9.1 Kernel Configuration**

> General setup ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

```
     ┌────────────────────── Preemption Model ───────────────────────┐
     │  Use the arrow keys to navigate this window or press the      │  
     │  hotkey of the item you wish to select followed by the <SPACE │  
     │  BAR>. Press <?> for additional information about this        │  
     │ ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐ │  
     │ │       ( ) No Forced Preemption (Server)                   │ │  
     │ │       ( ) Voluntary Kernel Preemption (Desktop)           │ │  
     │ │       (X) Preemptible Kernel (Low-Latency Desktop)        │ │  
     │ │                                                           │ │  
     │ │                                                           │ │  
     │ │                                                           │ │  
     │ └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘ │  
     ├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤  
     │                    <Select>      < Help >                     │
```

When I run:

```
make menuconfig
```

I do see that option though for the x86 option:
.config - Linux/**x86 5.9.1 Kernel Configuration**

> General setup ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

```
     ┌────────────────────── Preemption Model ───────────────────────┐
     │  Use the arrow keys to navigate this window or press the      │  
     │  hotkey of the item you wish to select followed by the <SPACE │  
     │  BAR>. Press <?> for additional information about this        │  
     │ ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐ │  
     │ │       ( ) No Forced Preemption (Server)                   │ │  
     │ │       ( ) Voluntary Kernel Preemption (Desktop)           │ │  
     │ │       (X) Preemptible Kernel (Low-Latency Desktop)        │ │  
     │ │       ( ) Fully Preemptible Kernel (Real-Time)            │ │  
     │ │                                                           │ │  
     │ │                                                           │ │
```

Linux Kernel: 5.9.1
Linux RT patch used: patch-5.9.1-rt19.patch.xz

I have enabled the expert mode also, as instructed in another post in unix.stackexchange
.config - Linux/x86 5.9.1 Kernel Configuration

> General setup ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> ┌────────────────────────────── General setup ───────────────────────────────┐
> │  Arrow keys navigate the menu.   selects submenus ---> (or empty    │
> │  submenus ----).  Highlighted letters are hotkeys.  Pressing  includes, │
> │   excludes,  modularizes features.  Press  to exit, <?>    │
> │  for Help, </> for Search.  Legend: [*] built-in  [ ] excluded   module │
>
> │ ┌────^(-)────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐ │
>
> │ │    [*]   Support initial ramdisk/ramfs compressed using LZMA           │ │
> │ │    [*]   Support initial ramdisk/ramfs compressed using XZ             │ │
>
> │ │    [*]   Support initial ramdisk/ramfs compressed using LZO            │ │
> │ │    [*]   Support initial ramdisk/ramfs compressed using LZ4            │ │
>
> │ │    [*]   Support initial ramdisk/ramfs compressed using ZSTD           │ │
> │ │    [ ] Boot config support                                             │ │
> │ │        Compiler optimization level (Optimize for performance (-O2))  --│ │
> │ │    -*- Configure standard kernel features (expert users)  --->         │ │
>
> │ │    -*- Enable membarrier() system call                                 │ │
> │ │    -*- Load all symbols for debugging/ksymoops                         │ │
>
> │ │    -*-   Include all symbols in kallsyms                               │ │
> │ │    [*] Enable bpf() system call                                        │ │
>
> │ │    [ ] Enable userfaultfd() system call                                │ │
>
> │ │    [*] Enable rseq() system call                                       │ │
> │ │    [ ]   Enabled debugging of rseq() system call                       │ │
> │ │    [*] Embedded system                                                 │ │
> │ │    [ ] PC/104 support                                                  │ │
> │ │        Kernel Performance Events And Counters  --->                    │ │

I see that this problem does not happen in the previous RT-patch that was released for Linux 5.6.19. Is there something missing for the 64-bit case from my side?

Comment: This item needs to be selected before the full preempt will show, i ran into the same problem. -- Configure standard kernel features (expert users) ---> │

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I raised it in Kernel.org, and then got a response that apparently it was intended to behave that way.

https://lore.kernel.org/linux-rt-users/20200824154605.v66t2rsxobt3r5jg@linutronix.de/

This basically meant that when we use 5.9.1 version with arm64 architecture, we need to disable KVM and then the Fully preemptible option comes up immediately. I was able to test it successfully.

Comment: exactly go to Virtualization and uncheck "Kernel-based virtual machine (KVM). then go back to General Setup/ Preemption Model and the missing option will appear.

Answer (score -1):

Run,

```
make mrproper
```

Now run,

```
make menuconfig
```

The Realtime option must be visible now.

Comment: did not work ... are you using arm64 ?